# Nightmare wont start up- syntax error in my coding (unexpected end of input)

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, nightmare

```
var Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true , height: 900});

const request = require('request');

request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function(error, response, body) {

const searchword = "Pinball";

const data = JSON.parse(body).products_and_categories;

const ids = [];

for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        data[key].map(item => {
            if (item.name.indexOf(searchword) >= 0) {
                ids.push(item.id);

console.log(ids[0]);

nightmare
.goto('http://www.supremenewyork.com/')
})
}
});
}
}
```

There is a syntax error in my code that is causing nightmare to not go to the url. I've tried to fix it but when I try to it brings in a new error so I am not sure where it originates from but any help would be great. I run my program using node coded in atom. here is the error I get:

```
});
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Answer (score 0):

found the error when closing my objects. Make sure to indent them correctly so that you know which are still open. Makes it easier to find the error. Atom shows which closing goes with its opening which helps out too.